# How to place order in magento 2 using REST API?

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

**Preconditions**

I have using REST API for placing order in PHP coding.
And then i have to set this to my android app.
**Steps to reproduce**

And i have following the steps of
a.) create empty cart b.) add items c.) post billing address d.) post estimate shipping methods e.) get shipping info f.) get payment info g.) place order
But Shipping Address is not set in my backend and the shipping methods returning empty array [ ].
Shipping info is also returning empty array.
billing address is generating the ID but it is not saving in my backend but it posts my address details..
Expected result

**For Example:**

Shipping Methods :

```
[
{
"carrier_code": "flatrate",
"method_code": "flatrate",
"carrier_title": "Flat Rate",
"method_title": "Fixed",
"amount": 15,
"base_amount": 15,
"available": true,
"error_message": "",
"price_excl_tax": 15,
"price_incl_tax": 15
},
{
"carrier_code": "tablerate",
"method_code": "bestway",
"carrier_title": "Best Way",
"method_title": "Table Rate",
"amount": 5,
"base_amount": 5,
"available": true,
"error_message": "",
"price_excl_tax": 5,
"price_incl_tax": 5
}
]
```

Actual result is attached in screenshot,
Thanks in advance